# What does this error mean for ImageMagick on XAMPP server?

Tags: php, xampp, imagemagick, imagick

So I'm trying to install `imagemagick` on XAMPP server. I installed the `php_imagick_ts.dll` on the ext folder under the PHP folder. I added the extension line in the `php.ini` file, but when I start APACHE on XAMPP , it says:

```
The procedure entry point MagickGetImageMatte could not be located in the dynamic CORE_RL_wan_.dll
```

Then it says:

```
PHP Startup : Unable to load dynamically library 'C:\xampp\ext\php_imagick_ts.dll. The specified procedure could not be found
```

How can I fix this error? I can't see to find a solution. I also installed `imagemagick` on the computer. Any help or suggestion would be appreciated

Answer (score 3):

The solution below worked for me! Thank you! Just to clarify:
I had exactly the same issues with same specs, Xampp 1.8.2, etc.

i had installed ImageMagick-6.8.8-9-Q16-x86-dll.exe

after reading this, I only replaced it with: ImageMagick-6.8.1-9-Q16-x86-dll.exe
downloaded from below mentioned ftp.sunet.se... link
and it worked, Apache started fine.

Answer (score 2):

I had the same problem. I'm using:

- Xampp 1.8.2
- Apache 2.4.4
- MySQL 5.5.32 (Community Server)
- PHP 5.4.19 (VC9 X86 32bit thread safe) + PEAR

Follow this tutorial http://thinktibits.blogspot.cz/2008/09/installing-imagemagick-on-windows-setup.html. **You have to restart your PC after step 8.** (this is not mentioned in the tutorial and you'll receive CORE dll error).

I have downloaded ImageMagick for Windows from [this site](http://ftp.icm.edu.pl/packages/ImageMagick/binaries/) (not the latest, dynamic lib) and dll from here http://www.peewit.fr/imagick/ (5.4, thread safe).

Hope it helps